# Как добавить данные в бд через хтмл checkbox

Tags: php, mysqli

Добрый день мастера хочу сделать чтобы с 3 checkbox брались данные активировал пользователь их или нет и эти данные проверялись и отправлялись в бд помогите это реализовать подключение к бд везде осуществляется через mysqli пробовал вводить так но не знаю какие запросы вводить так как таблица пуста и ид автоинк

```
    Укажите дополнительную информацию:<br /><form method="post" action=" ">
Вам нужен водитель ?  <input type="checkbox" name="usl_1" value="1" /><br />
Вам нужен навигатор в машину ? <input type="checkbox" name="usl_2" value="1" /><br />
С вами будет ребенок ?<input type="checkbox" name="usl_3" value="1" /> <br /><input type="submit" name="ок" value="Отправить форму" /></form>
<?
if ($_POST['usl_1'] == ''){}
else{
    $add1 = $mysqli->query ("INSERT INTO `zakaz` (`usluga_1`) VALUES ('1')");
}
?>
<?
if ($_POST['usl_2'] == ''){}
else{
    $add2 = $mysqli->query ("INSERT INTO `zakaz` (`usluga_2`) VALUES ('1')"");
}
?>
<?
if ($_POST['usl_3'] == ''){}
else{
    $add3 = $mysqli->query ("INSERT INTO `zakaz` (`usluga_3`) VALUES ('1')");
}
?>
```

но этот запрос у меня добавляет несколька записей и у каждой по порядку значение 1

Comment: Позвольте предположить, полное игнорирование всех правил правописания и оформления вопроса связано с: "пишу в попыхах, пятница, надо пивка попить, а тут  пусть правят, отвечают". Имейте же совесть.

Answer (score 0):

ураааааааааааааа!
простите за неточность и беспокойство  я уже сам додумался
получился вот такой вот код

```
<?php
$usluga_1   = addslashes ( $_POST['uslug_1'] ); 
$usluga_2   = addslashes ( $_POST['uslug_2'] ); 
$usluga_3   = addslashes ( $_POST['uslug_3'] ); 
if(isset($_POST['ok'])){
$add1 = $mysqli->query ("INSERT INTO `zakaz` (`usluga_1`, `usluga_2`, `usluga_3`) values ('".$usluga_1."', '".$usluga_2."', '".$usluga_3."')");
}
?>
<br>
<form action="" method="post">
    <fieldset>
        <legend>
            Укажите дополнительную информацию
        </legend>
        <label>
            Вам нужен водитель?
        </label>
        <input type="checkbox" name="uslug_1" value="1" title="Выбрать">
        <br>
        <label>
            Вам нужен навигатор в машину?
        </label>
        <input type="checkbox" name="uslug_2" value="1" title="Выбрать">
        <br>
        <label>
            С вами будет ребенок?
        </label>
        <input type="checkbox" name="uslug_3" value="1" title="Выбрать">
        <br>
        <button name="ok">Отправить форму</button>
    </fieldset>
</form>``
```